# how to replace the text read from the CreateReadStream in node js

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I'm reading a json file in node js using fs.CreateReadStream() and once the file is read I want to replace some text and again write it so that I can use this to download the file in my "/download" express js route.

My Question is, is there any possibility like this, I read from fs.CreateReadStream() and replace some text and make it ready for download without saving the file on memory.

I can download the file normally but I NEED TO REPLACE SOME TEXT AND MAKE IT READY FOR DOWNLOAD.

I have tried this ...

```
app.get("/download", function(req, res) {
    var fs = require("fs");
    const { uuid } = require('uuidv4');
    var data;
    var filename = "dashboard-" + (new Date()).toISOString() + ".ndjson";

    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream("C:/Files/node/download-file/lib/dashboard.ndjson");
    readableStream.setEncoding('utf8');

    readableStream.on("data", function(chunks) {
            data += chunks;
        })
        .on("end", function() {
            data.replace(/"description": *".*?"/g, '"description": "myyyyyyy new index"')
                .replace(/"title":" Dashboard --  0805"/, '"title":" Dashboard --  0805- *******"')
                .replace(/"id":"3f18d25a-ebe7-4c7b-9d84-c4d1ed07bfcf"/, '"id":"' + uuid() + '"')
                .replace(/"id":"y_0805"/g, '"id":"y_0805-testing"');
            console.log(data)

        })
        .on("error", function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    res.set('content-disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}"`);
    data.pipe(res)
})
```